# OpenGL ES 2.0 viewport

Tags: ios, rendering, opengl-es-2.0

I got a problem with OpenGL ES 2.0  and command Viewport(x,y,width,height).
I'm displaying texture(WxH) in UIView using render function

```
- (void)render
{
    glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glViewport(0,0,window_width,window_height);
    _openglViewer.render();
    [_context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER];
}
```

The problem is that texture displays normally only when it starts from portrait mode with
window_width = 768, window_height = 1004.0. With such sizes it works normal after rotation.
When i set depending like window_width = self.frame.size.width and window_height = self.frame.size.height and rotate  in landscape mode or start from it - texture displaying bigger in width and smaller in height than screen size.
Replacing "frame" with "bounds" doesn't solve problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found 2 bugs:

> 1 - why my texture after rotation get strange position

The problem is that texture displays normally only when it starts from portrait mode with window_width = 768, window_height = 1004.0. With such sizes it works normal after rotation. When i set depending like window_width = self.frame.size.width and window_height = self.frame.size.height and rotate in landscape mode or start from it - texture displaying bigger in width and smaller in height than screen size. Replacing "frame" with "bounds" doesn't solve problem.

I solved it by update context in overrided set frame method

```
- (void)setFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    [super setFrame:frame];
    _openglViewer.setWindowSize(frame.size.width, frame.size.height);
    [_context renderbufferStorage:GL_RENDERBUFFER
                     fromDrawable:(CAEAGLLayer *)self.layer];
    _openglViewer.setupVBOs();
    _openglViewer.compileShaders();
}
```

> 2 - why texture is displaying without saving ratio

Thanks Trax, i listened your advice and recalculated my projection matrix.

```
void calculateRatio (GLsizei &width, GLsizei &height, GLfloat &w, GLfloat &h)
{
    // The bigger side returns 1.0,
    // smaller - percentage value of bigger side
    GLfloat ratio = (GLfloat)width/(GLfloat)height;

    if(ratio < 1.0) {
        w = ratio;
        h = 1.0;
    } else {
        w = 1.0;
        h = 1.0/ratio;
    }
}
```

I call this method 2 times : 1) for getting texture ratio 2) for getting window ratio.
After I got this values i check

```
if(winW > winH) {
        w = texW*winH;
        h = texH;
    } else {
        w = texW;
        h = texH*winW;
    }
```

Now I have final ratio. My task was - render texture in maximum possible size adjusted to screen size. Thats why i normalize this ratio
normalizeSizes(w,h);

```
void normalizeSizes(GLfloat &w, GLfloat &h)
{
    // the smaller size get 1.0 value,
    // bigger - times it is bigger than smaller;
    bool isWider = false;
    GLfloat maxSize;
    if(w > h) {
        isWider = true;
        maxSize = w;
    } else {
       maxSize = h;
    }
    if(maxSize != 1.0) {
        if(isWider) {
            w = 1.0;
            h = h/maxSize;
        } else {
            h = 1.0;
            w = w/maxSize ;
        }
    }
    w = 1.0/w;
    h = 1.0/h;
}
```

After getting normalized value i generate projection matrix.

> projectionMatrix = tmp.genOrthoProjMatrix(-1.0, 1.0, -w, w, -h, h);

```
//genOrthoProjMatrix(float near ,float far ,float left, float right, float bottom, float top)
    // First Column
    res.p[0][0] = 2.0 / (right - left);
    res.p[1][0] = 0.0;
    res.p[2][0] = 0.0;
    res.p[3][0] = 0.0;

    // Second Column
    res.p[0][1] = 0.0;
    res.p[1][1] = 2.0 / (top - bottom);
    res.p[2][1] = 0.0;
    res.p[3][1] = 0.0;

    // Third Column
    res.p[0][2] = 0.0;
    res.p[1][2] = 0.0;
    res.p[2][2] = -2.0 / (far - near);
    res.p[3][2] = 0.0;

    // Fourth Column
    res.p[0][3] = -(right + left) / (right - left);
    res.p[1][3] = -(top + bottom) / (top - bottom);
    res.p[2][3] = -(far + near) / (far - near);
    res.p[3][3] = 1;
```

Everything is working now. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is more involved than just the `glViewport` (*which maps normalized device coordinates to window coordinates*). You will probably need to update you **projection matrix** to reflect the **change in aspect ratio** (the camera now *see* less top-down but has a wider angle right-left (or the inverse, depending on device orientation).

So basically recalculate projection matrix with these new device values (aspect ratio has changed).